# Get unique values from each column in R, comparing across all columns

Tags: r, list, dplyr, vector, unique

I have a dataset that looks similar to like this (used for venn diagram).

```
genes <- paste("gene",1:1000,sep="")
x <- list(
  A = sample(genes,300), 
  B = sample(genes,525), 
  C = sample(genes,440),
  D = sample(genes,350)
  )
```

I want to extract all the unique gene names from each list (A,B,C,D). Something like

```
A = gene100, gene667...
B = gene450, gene778...
C = gene359, gene889...
D = gene32, gene55...
```

This can be easily done in excel by conditional formatting all columns (the list of vectors as columns (A,B,C,D)). I need it in R to continue with additional analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by unique? That it only exists in that particular list and not in any of the others?

Comment: yes, only in one list and not the others.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option in base R:

```
freq_overall <- table(unlist(x)) # Assumes no reptition within each sublist
# freq_overall <- table(unlist(lapply(x, unique))) # If repitition within sublists

uniq_genes   <- names(freq_overall)[freq_overall == 1L]
lapply(x, \(lst) intersect(lst, uniq_genes))
```

A a more concise option but less efficient:

```
lapply(names(x), \(l) setdiff(x[[l]], unlist(x[setdiff(names(x), l)])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `purrr` + `dplyr` alternative:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
x |> 
  map_dfr(as_tibble, .id = "col_name") |> 
  group_by(value) |> 
  filter(row_number() == 1) |> 
  ungroup() %>%
  split(.$col_name)
```